# {oCanvas} How do I change the line coordinates through mouse clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to change the position of a line on the canvas through mouse clicks. It should detect the first click and change the end coordinates from the position of the mouse at the click. I can't seem to change the value of the end coordinates on my click function.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var canvas = oCanvas.create({
    canvas: "#myCanvas",
    background :"#808080"
});

var line = canvas.display.line({
    start: {x:80, y:60},
    end: {x:280, y:170},
    stroke: "10px #0aa",
    cap: "round"
});
canvas.addChild(line);

canvas.bind("click tap", function(){
    alert(line.start.x + "  " + canvas.mouse.x);
    line.end.x = canvas.mouse.x;
    line.end.y = canvas.mouse.y;
    canvas.redraw;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing parentheses for the function call for redraw. Add that and it should work. To make it work for touch as well, use canvas.pointer.x and canvas.pointer.y.